# Is there a screenshot functionality in The Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've found many scenes in The Witcher 3 to be very pretty and I'd like to record them by taking a screenshot.

Is it possible to take a screenshot actually in-game? If it is, how is it done?

I am playing the game on PC using the GOG Galaxy Beta client.

[Referring to this thread](http://www.gog.com/forum/the_witcher_3_wild_hunt/can_the_witcher_3_take_screenshots), it seems that the only way is a third party solution, such as Fraps or 'Non-Steam game' link and overlay, but are they correct in assuming the game has no built-in screenshot functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there is no Witcher 3 Functionality for Screenshots.

But **Yes** you can easily take screenshots of The Witcher 3.

I take screenshots of games in 2 ways.

### Steam Way

If you are playing Witcher 3 on **Steam** you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to take a screenshot while you are playing.

**NOTE**: This was the default key that came with my installation. You can change it in the settings.

If you have it on **GoG** you can open it as a non-steam game in steam and still use the functionality.

### MSI Afterbuner Way

The second option for me is using **MSI Afterburner**.

To enable screenshots you can:

1. Open MSI Afterburner
2. Go to Settings
3. Open tab "Screen Capture"
4. Set Default Key and desired folder for the shots
5. Open game and take screenshots at will

With **MSI** the advantage is that you can even choose the extension of the images generated.

Hope I helped

Comment: Think I might use Fraps or Overwolf.

Comment: Choose whichever one you like most. I will try some more to see which one gives me the most quality.

Comment: Also you can do it with EvolveHQ. Eg http://imgur.com/pP1oCIu

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if this is already been mentioned/discovered but you can take great screenshots in Witcher 3 w/out the UI showing using this "photo mode" mod/method:
http://www.gameranx.com/updates/id/28216/article/the-witcher-3-photo-mode-tool-allows-you-to-compose-fantastic-screenshots/

How it works:

- Install the mod files into your Witcher 3 folder (linked above)
- Launch the game / load your save / start playing
- Press "F2" and a console panel will slide down
- Type "dlgshow" and press "ENTER" to HIDE the UI (yes, no idea why the command has the word "show" in it)
- Press "F2" to hide the console panel
- Press your keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot w/whatever 3rd party screenshot utility you use (I use [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) and Ctrl+PrtScreen)
- When done, press "F2" again, type "dlghide" and press "ENTER" to bring back the UI
- Press "F2" again to hide the console and go back to playing the game!

It sounds (and is) a bit tedious but you get faster at it after a few times - and it's worth it for the great screenshots. I wish someone would create a single-button-press option for UI-free screens, but at least the above works.

[image: Man it's such a beautiful game!]

Comment: Hey @Chris-Emerson - cool answer (and nice screenshot), thanks for posting it! However, posting a link with no details about the content could end up with a dead-link in the answer. It would be awesome if you could elaborate a little about what the photo mode method is, in the post.

Comment: You can use HOME key to hide UI.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options to take a picture, in game.

- You can use third-party software, such as [Steam Overlay](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3182905) or [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/).
- You can press the print screen button on your keyboard, open image-editing software and paste it in
- On Windows 8, you can use the built-in screenshot app, by pressing both the Windows key, and the Print Screen button.

[image: The Elusive Print Screen Button]

Answer (score 2):

Why not it's possible.

To take a screenshot during gameplay Microsoft has developed a tool called Gamebar.

This tool created for PlayStation but as a windows 10 user, you can access it by pressing **Windows key + G**.

To [take a screenshot while gameplay](https://take-screenshot.org/on-windows/) Press the Windows key + G and click on the screenshot icon.

Comment: Strange that this answer has not been given before.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Nvidia graphics card, you can use the Nvidia Ansel photo mode, which lets you do things like rotate Geralt out of the Frame, adjust the field of view or camera angle, add filters and more.

Just make sure you have an up to date Nvidia driver, and hit <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Read more [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/nvidia-ansel-for-the-witcher-3-available-now/)

Comment: This has become my go to option for in-game photos. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could download the AMD Gaming Evolved overlay (aka Raptr which is the unbranded version of the same application which also works with Nvidia).

You can do screenshots, video capture and more with that tool.

Download from:
http://raptr.com/amd
or
http://raptr.com/download

If you have an AMD graphics card, I highly recommend downloading the 15.5 beta drivers for use with the Witcher 3, as they have some dedicated optimisations. Also the AMD Gaming Evolved (Raptr) overlay will optimse Witcher 3 settings.

And yes, Witcher 3 is utterly stunning.

Answer (score 1):

On Win10 you can use the in-build screenshot tool:

1. Press Win + print
2. Window will flicker
3. Find screenshots in `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots`

Results in a 4 MB PNG file for 1920x1080 by default.

[image: example downsized screenshot taking by the ingame tool]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO

Long Answer: There seems to be a folder for screenshots in install location of the witcher 3, the only problem is that there at this time isn't any key binding to take a screenshot ingame. Maybe they'll add this in a future update or maybe they made a mistake between the console and the pc version.

At the moment there isn't a way to take a screenshot without third party software.

After the comment from Kevin: You could always do it through paint or something via prntscrn and ctrl + v. The reason I didn't add this was because I couldn't do it with my pc.

Comment: As LokiSinclair said, there is always the "prntscrn -> ctrl+v in paint/photoshop" way. So short answer: yes, but not convenient.

Comment: @Kevin I tried it and prntscrn doesn't work in the witcher. But maybe that's my own pc and not in general, but i'm speaking about my own experiences and the stuff i found on the web.

Answer (score -1):

Actually if you press <kbd>PrintScr</kbd>, the game will save PNG files next to the 'witcher.exe' file in the same directory.

Ok, my bad. To me it works, because I installed ReShade with SweetFX 2.0 Pack. I tried now without the dlls and PrintScr won't work without them.