# What are the little red arrows on the minimap?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm actually at the cemetery at White Orchard. There is a white question mark and some little red arrows.

What are this little red arrows? 
Do they point to something dangerous?

Comment: I also thought they are some enemies at first. Which was very confusing, especially in areas where there were clearly no enemies, no heartbeats visible or anything. Then I figured out what they are, and thought that red colour is a bad design choice (considering that red circles are enemies). Then I thought that otherwise, it would be hard to discern them, so maybe it is not so bad.

Comment: These arrows are particularly helpful when there is something underground. One of the things I hate about Assassin's Creeds is those map markers which point to a place I can't find for life, only to end up reaching them through some obscure underground entrance (in a guide dangit moment).  Wild Hunt does a good job of marking the cave entrances and telling us when something is underground.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Without a screenshot, I'm guessing you mean the (altitude) location indicators.

These little red arrows indicate that an object is above (arrow points upwards) or below (arrow points downwards) your current location.

Comment: Can I make a screenshot inside the game? I have not found a working keyboard key for that :(

Comment: @PeterCo - Yeah, I read that taking screenshots in witcher 3 can be difficult. Someone asked a [question about that](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220386/is-it-possible-to-take-screenshots-in-game), so that might help.

Comment: Exactly my thought. This can easily be confirmed if the arrow shows together with another icon.